# What causes "Page Not Found" messages with a "null" path as the log message, even when the page is displayed correctly?

Tags: routes

Once every four or five pages I visit, I get "Page not found" messages in my log, even though the page is found and displays properly.  The errors suggest part of the page path is null.

For example, if I visit a (node) page like...

```
https://www.example.com/path/to/my-page-title-slug
```

...I get a "page not found" warning in the log, and the message in the log is simply...

```
/path/to/null
```

In the log entry, the "Location" is...

```
https://www.example.com/path/to/null
```

...and the referrer is...

```
https://www.example.com/path/to/my-page-title-slug
```

In every case, the page displays correctly.  To be clear, the pages are nodes.

In what appears to be a related issue, I have also found that if I have a simple custom page like...

```
/**
   * Test page.
   *
   * @return array
   *   A simple renderable array.
   */
  public function my_page($some_arg) {

    \Drupal::logger('mei_library')->notice($some_arg);

    $output['my_key'] = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => t('hey there'),
    );

    return $output;

  }
```

I will see two messages in the log: one with the appropriate value for $some_arg, and one with a null value for $some_arg.  The log entry with the appropriate value for $some_arg appears first, followed directly by the log entry of "null".

What could possibly be causing the logger method to fire twice?  And how could $some_arg ever be null?

I am seeing this happen in Drupal 8.8.2 and 8.8.3.

Comment: This is not unusual that a page is loading more resources from the web server. The naming of the path is very unusual, though. Looks like a dummy path someone forgot to remove. You have a good chance to find the path in the HTML source of the original request or in code you have added in extensions.
.

Comment: My examples in the question use fake paths.  Maybe I should clarify that.  I don't actually have a "path/to/my-page-title-slug" page.  But if the slug is my-awesome-slug and the path is path/to/my-awesome-slug, then I will also see a log entry referencing "path/to/null".

Comment: Whatever the path is, did you check the HTML source and module/themes PHP/JS for code loading web server resources?